# Hierarchial Query to bring the root element for all leaf element

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table ABC with the following columns

| AO | AOM |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 |
| 200 | 300 |
| 300 | 400 |
| 600 | 500 |
| 500 | 300 |
| 800 | 900 |
| 800 | 1000 |
| 900 | 1000 |
| 1200 | 1300 |
| 100 | 1200 |
| 1500 | 1600 |
| 100 | 1600 |

and if we see here we can see that 100 is the root element and has following leaf elements 200,300,400,500,600,1200,1300

I will need my output to look like below:

list of all the elements and the corresponding root element

| ELEMENT | ROOT |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 |
| 200 | 100 |
| 300 | 100 |
| 400 | 100 |
| 500 | 100 |
| 600 | 100 |
| 1200 | 100 |
| 1300 | 100 |
| 800 | 800 |
| 900 | 800 |
| 1000 | 800 |
| 1500 | 100 |
| 1600 | 1600 |

I tried using the below query as a starting point but was not sure on how to get the expected value

select *
from ABC
start with ao=100
connect by ao = prior aom;

Comment: The leaves are the rows with no children so 400, 600, 900 & 1300 would be leaves but the rest would be part of the branches (to continue the tree metaphor) of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to reverse the question and treat each element as the root and then navigate back up to the ancestors until you reach a leaf (an element with no children):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT element, root
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT aom AS aom,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT ao  AS ao,
         ao AS root
  FROM   abc
  WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  CONNECT BY PRIOR ao = aom
)
UNPIVOT (
  element FOR type IN (ao, aom)
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE abc (AO, AOM) AS
SELECT  100,  200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  200,  300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  300,  400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  600,  500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  500,  300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  800,  900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  800, 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  900, 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1200, 1300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  100, 1200 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ELEMENT | ROOT |
> | --- | --- |
> | 100 | 100 |
> | 200 | 100 |
> | 300 | 100 |
> | 500 | 600 |
> | 300 | 600 |
> | 400 | 100 |
> | 400 | 600 |
> | 600 | 600 |
> | 800 | 800 |
> | 900 | 800 |
> | 1000 | 800 |
> | 1200 | 100 |
> | 1300 | 100 |

*Note: `600` is a root because you have the rows in your data set as `600, 500` and `500, 300` and not `500, 600` and `300, 500`. If the `ao` and `aom` values in those rows were reversed then the root would be `100` for all those rows.*

---

You can start from the roots and work down to the descendants but its less efficient as you need a sub-query to find the roots:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       element,
       root
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT ao AS root,
         ao,
         aom
  FROM   abc
  START WITH ao NOT IN (SELECT aom FROM abc)
  CONNECT BY PRIOR aom = ao
)
UNPIVOT (
  element FOR type IN (ao, aom)
)
```

*The output is identical.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0f281354d86049e1f3a63dab501c5c2f)*

Comment: adding 2 more records like 1500,1600 and 100,16000 to the input data breaks the query

Comment: @HariPrasshanth `CONNECT BY NOCYCLE ...` (however, if you do have cycles then the cycle has no root and no leaves so it is unclear what you want as output in that case.)